# embed rChart in Markdown

Tags: r, rcharts, nvd3.js

I am trying to embed a NVD3 chart in a Markdown document. I am on a Ubuntu64 system with RStudio 0.98.932, R 3.1.0, rCharts 0.4.2, the browser is Chrome.

The instructions/code from [this](http://bl.ocks.org/ramnathv/raw/8084330/) link:

````
 ```{r}

library(rCharts)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(comment = NA, results = "asis", comment = NA, tidy = F)

hair_eye_male = subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = 'Eye', 
  data = hair_eye_male, type = 'multiBarChart'
)
n1$set(width = 600)
# n1$show('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)  # option 1
# n1$show('inline', include_assets = TRUE, cdn = TRUE)  # option 2
```
````

Neither of the options [n1$show] work, I just get code in a browser. Is there another way of including NVD3 documents in Markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working for me. I am using ubuntu64 and same config you mentioned.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE,results='asis',comment=NA}
library(rCharts)
hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, type = "multiBarChart")
n1$show('iframesrc',cdn=TRUE)
```
````

Note : you **must write results='asis' and comment = NA** in **chunk options** and not use `opts_chunk$set` as you have in your code block and what you pasted to copy.com.

Comment: Thanks koundy. You are right, the comment = NA appears twice, this is in the original code that I copy/pasted. Somehow the code does not work. When I knit HTML there is just code in a browser. I must be doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: It doesn't. As said in the comment, there is just code in the browser. No graph.

Comment: you should be connected to internet and wait for sometime say 1-2 minutes for the chart to appear.

Comment: I do not see anything that looks wrong with the code.  Could you post the .Rmd and .html as a gist or on some other sharing site to see if I can reproduce your error?

Comment: @timelyportfolio : https://copy.com/paeRvRDKCYTr [sessionInfo], https://copy.com/NRCxrEV83xfn [html], https://copy.com/x1pddZTCRktK [Rmd].

Comment: sorry, I did not see this before, but `opts_chunk$set` does not apply to the current chunk, so you will need to start with

    ```{r results='asis'}
    ...
    ````

and you can eliminate the `opts_chunk$set` line.

Comment: which koundy alluded to, but appears the change did not get put into the code you posted to copy.com. You can then eliminate the opts_chunk$set line.  I added some bold to make sure this gets communicated in @koundy answer.

Comment: @timelyportfolio yeah thats what i meant. thanks for improving the answer. by the way im following your blog. good work. keep it up..:)

Comment: thanks timelyportfolio and koundy. it works now. Knit HTML opens in blank window, but opens correctly in browser.

Answer (score 4):

To get rCharts to work with knit2html, you will need to use the print method with the argument `include_assets = TRUE`. This is because knitr will not add the js and css assets required by an rCharts plot automatically. Here is a minimal working example.

````
## MorrisJS with Knit2HTML

```{r results = 'asis', comment = NA}
require(rCharts)
data(economics, package = 'ggplot2')
econ <- transform(economics, date = as.character(date))
m1 <- mPlot(x = 'date', y = c('psavert', 'uempmed'), type = 'Line',
  data = econ)
m1$set(pointSize = 0, lineWidth = 1)
m1$print('chart2', include_assets = TRUE)
```
````

Note that you need to use `m1$print('chart2', include_assets = TRUE, cdn = TRUE)` if you intend to publish your chart on RPubs, for otherwise the JS and CSS assets will be served from your local library.

Source:[Knitr HTML in R Markdown](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/NMpCJe5h3jg)