# rChart in R Markdown doesn't render

Tags: r, nvd3.js, r-markdown, rcharts

I am having issues rendering an rChart made with 'nPlot' when I knit an R Markdown document to html.

I followed the solution discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611845/embed-rchart-in-markdown), but it was unsuccessful.

Here is my .Rmd code

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Test"
date: "01/23/2015"
output: html_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

# Here is an rChart
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis', comment=NA}
library(rCharts)
m2 <- nPlot(speed ~ dist, data = cars, type = "scatterChart")
m2$show('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)
```
That was an rChart
````

Here is a [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5550126/test2.html) to the html document from that code.  I produced and authored this in RStudio and the rendering fails to show up both on my local machine and when uploaded to Dropbox.

When I run the following code in console and save as an html, I get [this rendering](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5550126/test3.html).

```
library(rCharts)
m2 <- nPlot(speed ~ dist, data = cars, type = "scatterChart")
m2$save('test3.html', standalone = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GOT IT.

see this answer: [Ramnath layin' it down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176191/3618859)

*(chest-swelling feeling of satisfaction quickly deflated upon realization we were just looking at outdated tutorials / walkthroughs...)*

last line should be

```
n1$print('iframesrc', cdn =TRUE, include_assets=TRUE)
```

I think most of the tutorials out there are using an old version or something. But the above works for me, so give it a shot.

then knit, then you're good to go. Also make sure you're rCharts library is up to date

```
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts")
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I had no success with either of those suggestions

Comment: Ugh... sorry.  I've got the same problem you do.  The above code seems to be identical to every example/walkthrough I've been able to dig up, but its just shows up blank.  I'm on a windows box using chrome if it matters.

Comment: @user3334472, see above.  We were looking at expired tutorials.

Comment: Super.  One note in case someone stumbles on this page: I encountered css errors with your code, due to the `cdn`. My working code is simply: `m1$print('iframesrc', include_assets = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding an updated answer here because I struggled for a long time with many outdated tutorials to get this to actually work. Also, the current answer here did not work for me.

This does work...

````
```{r set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
options(RCHART_WIDTH = 1000, RCHART_HEIGHT = 400)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, cache=T, results='asis', comment=NA}
p1 <- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = 'cyl', data = mtcars, type = 'scatterChart')
p1$print('chart1', include_assets=T)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, cache=T, results='asis', comment=NA}
hair_eye = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
p2 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = 'Eye', data = subset(hair_eye, Sex == "Female"), type = 'multiBarChart')
p2$print('chart2', include_assets=T)
```
````

Note:

- I needed to set `results='asis'` and `comment=NA` in the chunk with the chart code, not the options block at the top.
- `cdn=T` caused errors for me. R was looking for a public file and could not find it.
- The charts each need a unique name or they will override or chart on top of each other.
- You can update the height and width of your charts in the options chunk
- I have R 3.1.2, rCharts_0.4.5, rmarkdown_0.7

Answer (score 0):

You can save your rChart plot as a html and then include it to the RMarkdown document with `shiny::includeHTML("plot.html")`. This worked for me.