# knitr rchart datatable dtable does not to render

Tags: r, datatables, knitr, rcharts

First, excuse my english, second i've read:

- [rChart in R Markdown doesn't render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120267/rchart-in-r-markdown-doesnt-render)
- [2 Knitr/R Markdown/Rstudio issues: Highcharts and Morris.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168464/2-knitr-r-markdown-rstudio-issues-highcharts-and-morris-js/17176191#17176191)

and doing that, I still have problems

I install rCharts doing

**Install rCharts**

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts")
library("knitr")
```

If I have a .Rmd like

**test.Rmd**

````
```{r ,results='asis', comment= NA,  echo=FALSE}
library(rCharts)
tab2 <-  dTable(as.data.frame(summary(cars)))
# tab2$show('inline', include_assets= TRUE, cdn= TRUE)
tab2$print('chart2', include_assets= TRUE, cdn= TRUE)
```
````

when I run

```
knit2html(input = 'test.Rmd', output = 'test.html')
```

test.html does not render (I tried with `tab2$show` and `tab2$print`). But if I open test.html with a editor it can be read the following

```
<p><link rel='stylesheet' href=//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css></p>
<script type='text/javascript' src=//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script>
```

which seems to be incorrect because there is no `http:` at first for every `src` or `href`, so I put `http:` on that changing to

```
<p><link rel='stylesheet' href=http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css></p>
<script type='text/javascript' src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script>
```

and before that, test.html does render!!. So I don't know if i miss a parameter or this is a bug, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove cdn from the print function to use local JS and CSS.

```
tab2$print('chart2', include_assets= TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works!.. But if I understood well, it will work only in my PC, what do I have to do to work in any PC? Should I to use a Web Server?